# Clear rails input field content if validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, erb

I want to display error messages inside my input fields so I'm doing this by placing them inside the placeholder:

```
<%= f.input :age, label: false, placeholder: "#{f.object.errors.messages.has_key?(:age) ? f.object.errors.messages[:age].join(", ") : "Age*"}" %>
```

This is my model validation for age:

```
validates :age, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 18 }
```

However, if I submit age with value `11`, I will have a red bordered input field with the value `11`.
How can I clear the input field if validation fails to pass?

I tried with a custom validation method, something like:

```
  validate :minimum_age

  def minimum_age
    if age < 18
      self.errors.add(:age, "must be at least 18 years old!")
      self.age = nil
    end
  end
```

This will clear the field, but when it renders the view, I'll also have `a 'field must not be empty'` error, because I just made it nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<%= f.input :age, label: false, placeholder: "your code", value: nil %>
```

By the way, you might want to extract your placeholder message into helper method, it's little mess now, lol

Like:

```
def render_error_message(f, key)
  f.object.errors.messages.has_key?(key) ? f.object.errors.messages[:age].join(", ") : "Age*"}
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= f.input :age, label: false, placeholder: render_error_message(f, :age), value: nil %>
```

Comment: Definetly not leaving repeating code for 20 input lines :) thanks, value: nil should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could just clear that field if it has errors:

```
unless @user.valid?
  @user.age = nil if @user.errors.include?(:age)
end
```

Comment: Sure, but after setting it to nil inside the controller, in my f.object.age.errors I'll also have the presence :true validation error. But I'll upvote your suggestion :)

Comment: That's because you just `render :new` so rails just render view without running controller code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very awkward requirement you have; still if you want to clear the value then I would suggest do it in view instead of model or you may choose to do it using JS.

Comment: haha why awkward? All I want to do is display error messages inside placeholders :D

Comment: @BogdanPopa Normally placeholders are for hints and we tend to show error messages along the line of input.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it by setting `f.object.age = ""`

```
<%= f.input :age, label: false, placeholder: "#{f.object.errors.messages.has_key?(:age) ? "#{f.object.age = ""}Vârstă*" + " " + "( #{f.object.errors.messages[:age].join(", ")} )" : "Vârstă*"}" %>
```